# Testdome two sum functions error

Tags: c#

I try to solve this answer into [testdome](https://www.testdome.com/questions/c-sharp/twosum/4318) webpage

Code:

```
public static Tuple<int, int> FindTwoSum(IList<int> list, int sum)
{
    var lookup = list.Select((x, i) => new { Index = i, Value = x })
                     .ToLookup(x => x.Value, x => x.Index);

    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
    {
        int diff = sum - list[i];
        if (lookup.Contains(diff))
            return Tuple.Create(i, lookup[diff].First());
    }

    return null;
}
```

But I get an error:

> TwoSum.cs(8,23): error CS1061: 'System.Collections.Generic.IList' does
>   not contain a definition for 'Select' and no extension method 'Select'
>   accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList'
>   could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

Can anyone help me how can I solve it? Regards

Comment: You are missing using System.Linq; in namespace. Select is an Extension method not available in System.Collection.Generic namespace but in System.Linq namespace.

Comment: I've rolled back the change that you've made - please don't convert one question into another especially after answers are given. You may instead ask new question (you can get your version by http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/41626044/2).

Comment: omg sorry @AlexeiLevenkov

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add this namespace

```
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: beat me to it. ;-)

Comment: I change code to no use extension but now I have another problem, can you read again my question please?

Answer (score 0):

Your code compiles fine in my editor, Then I have tried in the Attached link but it shows the specified error, But we can resolve that by adding the namespace `using System.Linq;`

Comment: I change code to no use extension but now I have another problem, can you read again my question please?

Comment: @Veronica If you have another problem - ask another question. "Chameleon questions" considered bad practice on SO or any of StackExchange sites - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions